# saving userType in ReactJs thorughout the session

Tags: reactjs, express, session, cookies, local-storage

I am using **ReactJs** and **Nodejs** with **mysql** as my backend, I am maintaining user session via **express-session** and setting cookie header in my browser. The problem is that I want to display components based on role (eg.admin or user). I am sending the userType from database to React app,in response to the successful login.
How can I maintain and store this ***userType*** througout the session so that I can manage my roles.
I dont think local Storage is a good option.

P.S: I have also key:value pair of userType inside the cookie which I am receiving in my browser.but I dont know how to extract userType from the cookie

Comment: Do you have some sort of main store that you could save the role to? Or you could save the role to state when they log in, then update that whenever updating the cookie.

Comment: No,currently I am not using any kind of store in react.I know storing the user type as state in main component and then passing it as props to other component is an option but is it a best practice?

Comment: how can I extract the user type or any information from the encrypted cookies in react

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are having a single cookie, ie userType, you can simple do this in componentDidMount or any other applicable control location:

```
let userType = document.cookie.split("=")[1]
console.log(userType) //your cokkie value
```

Else, if there are many cookies, you can follow this:

```
var cookies= {};
document.cookie.split(/\s*;\s*/).forEach(function(pair) {
    pair = pair.split(/\s*=\s*/);
    cookies[pair[0]] = pair.splice(1).join('=');
});
console.log(cookies.userType)
```

Answer (score 0):

Storing in a cookie/local storage is fine you just have to make sure the user is authenticated server-side for a certain privilege.

Comment: storing the user type in plain text in local storage is fine? do we have seperate local storage for each website?I dont think so

Comment: Personally I would never do it since on first load you will probably pull for some user data somewhere so while you do that you could just get the user type data then. But there is localstorage for each domain. I would say a lot of times that I use localstorage it would be for something like user options (small example but if the user was using light or dark mode on a site, and I would still pass to the database if needed). But I mean you could pass the user type in a JWT token as a cookie.